# Switch locations on google map using a dropdown

Tags: google-maps

I'm new to google maps, and I have a map with multiple markers, and I want to switch between them using a dropdown menu.

I'm using this code to populate the dropdown menu with the markers' title:

```js
// select a marker from dropdown menu
$("select#mySelect").change(function(){ 
      gotoMarker($(this).val()); 
});

function makeMarkerList() {
        var options = "";
        $("select#mySelect").empty();
        for (var i in markers) {
            options += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + markers[i].map.title + "</option>";
        }
        $("select#mySelect").html(options);
}
```

This is what I have so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymLvv/157/)

this shows a dropdown menu above the map, but I don't know how to get the markers titles in the dropdown menu.

I appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you pretty much have it.  In the makeMarkerList function instead of markers[i].map.title just do markers[i].title.  I didn't see anything calling this function but you would want to do something like the following to make sure that function gets called after the document is loaded: `$(document).ready(function() { makeMarkerList(); });`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the dropdown menu to have marker titles as options. Now, I have added map.panTo() to center the selected marker on the map, but still don't work.. can you help on this? this is the upated jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ymLvv/167/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second problem: Your original code, shown below, was trying to pass the value of the selected item in the drop down list to the `panTo()` method. However, due to the way you've set that up, that value is just the index of the markers in your `markers` array and not a `LatLng` object. Passing that index to the `panTo()` method generates an error.

```
$("select#mySelect").change(function(){ 
      //gotoMarker($(this).val());
    map.panTo($(this).val().getPosition());
});
```

To fix that, get the index and then use the corresponding marker from your `markers` array:

```
$("select#mySelect").change(function(){ 
    var index = $(this).val();
    map.panTo(markers[index].position);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help.. now when I manually add the LatLng value to the select option value, the panTo no longer moves.. the alert shows correct values though. I appreciate if you can check my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymLvv/187/) thanks

Comment: Here is a [working fiddle based on your latest one](http://jsfiddle.net/sunild/ydmK2/). Since you've changed the values in the `select` to now be a comma separated String containing the latitude/longitude, you now need to construct a new `LatLng` object from that string. Also, while your select says the locations are California and DC, the actual lat/lng values you're using are nowhere near those locations ;)

Comment: I was wrong in thinking that the value returned doesn't need to be split.. thank you Sunil :)